# Spring Cache: How to specify global @CacheConfig for application

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, spring-cache

I am working on setting up [Spring Cache](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) support for my Java application. I want a way to set a global [@CacheConfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheConfig.html) for my entire project because I want all cache operations in the application to use the exact same *cache name* and *custom KeyGenerator implementation*. I was hoping that I could annotate some global configuration class or my `CacheManager` with `@CacheConfig`, but it looks like `@CacheConfig` is only meant as configuration for the class of the method with the Cache Annotation. Thus, I would need to use the same exact `@CacheConfig` annotation definition for every class using Spring Cache operations.

A workaround that I'm going to use in the meanwhile is implement my own *meta-annotation* of Spring Cache annotations such as `@Cacheable`, so that the same exact `name` and `keyGenerator` will be used for all cache operations. But, there must be a better way to do this than using custom annotations. If I ever run into the situation where I want to use a Cache named something other than "default", then I'm going to run into trouble with my custom annotation.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is doable.

All you need is to populate [AnnotationCacheOperationSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/annotation/AnnotationCacheOperationSource.java) with your own `CacheAnnotationParser`, see how is it done by default: [SpringCacheAnnotationParser](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/annotation/SpringCacheAnnotationParser.java).

Unfortunately I can't provide you with code snippets, my Spring-fu is too weak at this moment. If you manage to get this working - let me know.